# Deselect selected text in sql server management studio table-design cell w/out using mouse

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

This is something that has bothered me for years. When I am using SQL Server 2005 Management Studio and I am in the table designer and I'm editing the column definitions It is almost possible to do this entirely without using the mouse.  However, if I'm navigating around the cells in this designer using the arrow keys, when I move to a new cell all the text is selected.  Say I want to change a decimal(6,2) to decimal(6,3), so I move over there with arrow keys and the whole decimal(6,2) phrase is selected.  I have been completely unsuccessful in finding a way to move the cursor to the beginning or end of the line.  Instead any combination of ctrl, shift, alt and arrow keys blithely select the adjacent cell in that arrow's direction.  So inevitably, I have to take my hands from the keyboard and use the mouse to click within the cell I want to edit and then I can edit the value without having to retype the entire thing.

GRRR!

Can anyone help me out with this one?

I will be eternally grateful (or at least as long as I use Sql server management studio)!

Thanks,

Comment: A query window lets your write a `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` statement entirely using the keyboard. <insert cruel comment about the table designer here>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uh... F2, right? That's always worked for me, in just about any program where you edit a grid

Comment: Yeah, I just figured this out and came back to answer the question after all this time.  Glad someone got it.

Answer (score 3):

While playing around with @Damien's answer I found out an even better answer that I basically accept as the answer.

If you move to a cell and all the text is selected you can hit the escape key.  All the text will still be selected but at this point you can use the navigation keys like arrows and Home and End and they will work as expected.

Comment: I deleted this answer for some reason, but today was struggling with the same issue, tried my solution and it works... so maybe there is some condition that I can't remember that makes this answer invalid, but if you are searching try this.

Comment: This has bothered me for years too.  Today I found your suggestion of using the <ESC> key to get the arrows to behave as expected.  Thanks for that -- it ain't perfect but it is sooooo much better than nothing!

Comment: This no longer works for me in SQL Server.  However, hitting F2 does and is the real answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is ugly, but you can do it with 3 keyboard actions: SPACE, CTRL-Z, RIGHT ARROW leaves the cursor at the end of the text, left arrow is then moving the cursor within the text.

But as I said in my comment, I'd just use a query window and write the SQL directly rather than using the table designer.

Comment: Well, I like to see my table definition as I edit it, and I find the object explorer annoying to expand out the columns because of all the useless folders that have to be displayed as well.